# Insert or update (if row with key exists) a pack of rows

Tags: mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

My aim is to upload csv data to myisam table: if any row in myisam table has primary key duplicate, update some fields, otherwise - insert new row. For simple inserting i was reading csv line by line, and after every 5000th line i was making an INSERT query like

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (), (), (), () ..5k times..,()
```

For my current aim, i should use query like

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (), (), ()...,() ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1=value1, field2=value2, ...
```

but it will use value1 and value2 for each row to update. I want it to update with respective values. Hope you understand all written before...

Comment: 'Hope you understand all written before' - sorry,no , it's not compulsory that you update all columns so i'm not with you . Do you mean in some cases you might want to update field1 only and in some cases field2 only (for example) Or are you saying you have a problem inserting your dummy row every 5k?

Comment: @P.Salmon no, in second query it will always update row with constant value1 and value2, but i want it to update row with respective values. For example, we have three groups of values like "VALUES (), (), ()". If key from some group exists in myisam table, update with values from this group.

Comment: Nope don't get it, Sample data and expected result might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use references to VALUES to do this:

```sql
INSERT INTO `user`(`username`, `password`) VALUES ('ersks','Nepal'), ('segesg','esgessgs'), ('segsegss','segsege')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `username`='master',`password`=VALUES(b);
```

See docs here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html